# Is there really multiple iterations of an IEnumerable in this code?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var element in source) action(element);
        return source;
    }
```

The code above gives me a warning that source is potentially iterated multiple times, but is it really? It's iterated once in the foreach statement, but how does the return statement make it iterated again?

Comment: Well in certain sense, because you return it back to the caller and what caller can do with `IEnumerable`? Only enumerate it again. Like in `myList.ForEach(c => DoStuff(c)).ToArray()` < double enumeration. It may be better to first materialize ienumerable into array (because you are going to iterate over all elements anyway), execute action for each item and then return that array instead of IEnumerable. Or just return void.

Comment: Is it possible to have delayed execution on elemenents in an enumerable?

Answer (score 4):

The return doesn't iterate the enumerable again. But you are returning it, and since the only way you could possibly do ANYTHING with this result is to iterate it elsewhere, this warning is given.

Why return it if you are not going to iterate it later?

Comment: Yes, it will be re-iterated. I wanted a Linq version of ForEach so I can do things like list.ForEach(x=>x.Number++).Where(x=>x.Number > 3).Etc...

Comment: Just use select. For instance:

list.Select(x => x++).Where(x => x > 3)

Answer (score 1):

In the current code you show there is only one iteration. It is very well possible that you are enumerating it again somewhere else since the same enumerable is returned. That is what the warning is telling you.

My personal preference would be to change the return type of the `ForEach` to `void`, and add a second one that returns the result of a `Func<T, R>`.

So:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var element in source)
        action(element);
}
```

And:

```
public static IEnumerable<R> ForEach<T, R>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, R> action)
{
    foreach (var element in source)
        yield return action(element);
}
```

That way you are never accidentally reusing the same enumerable and you are making it lazy: it won't execute before you actually call the enumerable.

Comment: The second one should work; but, it could 'possibly' violate the OP's type constraints.

Comment: Why is that? @AlyEl-Haddad

Comment: Because in his method, he guarantees that the type of the returned `IEnumerable` will be the same as the source one. Here, the type of the returned `IEnumerable` 'may' differ depending on the function parameter; and that's why I said "possibly". @Patrick Hofman